# how to install libOAuth.a for twitter + oauth in iphone app

Tags: ios, twitter, ios7, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

I have installed twitter + oauth library into my project. Its working fine while I am running my app on simulator but when I run my app into my device or archiving my app to generate ipa it shows me an error like below given image - [image]

when I faced such issue I have made settings in my project file as shown in below images - 
In Target - [image]

In target which I have shown in above image I have made changes on other linker flag as **-lz**, in header search path as - **iphoneos/usr/include/libxml2** and in library search paths. The changes in above field which I have made in target like as given below images - 
[image]

I have also made change in project part as given below image in **other linker flag,header search path and library search path** - [image]

guys, I'm not able to generate .ipa or run in device due to above generated error. PLease, provide me a solution to resolve this error. and provide me guidence where am I going wrong. Your help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: thanks zap now it is archiving ...

Comment: zaph please answer me of question i want to upvote you on your commented answer. thanks a lot zaph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error: "missing required architecture arm64" says it all. The library does not have arm64. Get another library that supports arm64 or eliminate arm64 from the target in Valid Architectures.

Comment: I have removed architecture arm64.

Comment: Zaph I have made change as you have provided me a solution. my question is - shall I face an issue if I have made a change as provided solution given by to you while I will submit my app on app-store?

Comment: I am not sure about the iOS7 rules, in the past similar solutions have been allowed.